# How should I clean-up multiple python mess?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, windows-10

I was going to start learning python with `VSCode`. The first step was to select an interpreter. After I typed the command I was pretty surprised that I already have  three of them installed :o

[image]

This is very confusing. Could you tell me how did it happen that I have multiple pythons? Which of them should I keep or update in future?

What's even more bizarre is that all three versions are different.

Comment: You could really use any of them... for a beginner they all will behave the same.  Now, if you had 2.7 installed then that would be slightly different.  You can keep them all or just delete two of them... whatever makes you happy :)

Comment: [I know that feeling.](https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/python_environment.png)

Comment: @BilalSaleem ok, that's good to know; then I'll keep them all and use the latest one as I have no idea how I installed the two from Visual Studio. I guess I must have accidentaly selected some option in the installer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't really matter, and you'll even have more if you use virtual environments.  I would take the latest one (3.7) as default, but you can take anaconda if you need any of the whistles and bells that are already installed there.  In 3.7 you would have to pip install all of them.